# Access PHP Object from a loaded PHP in POST request

Tags: php, variables, object, request

I have an object instantiated in my `main.php`, which have properties and member variables. I POST-request on the server for `other.php`. Now, in `other.php` I need to access that object I instantiated in `main.php`, so I can use the values I have manipulated in that object.

**How to do it?**

[image]

Comment: Show the code you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in the `$_SESSION` and access it on the other pages.

On each page that you will use it you have to include the class.

So on both main.php and other.php:

```
require 'thisClass.php';
session_start();
```

On main.php

```
$_SESSION['obj'] = $obj;
```

And on other.php

```
$obj = $_SESSION['obj'];
```

and you can use the object.